# Ordering UIApplicationShortcutItems (3D Touch)

Tags: ios, swift2

Implementing 3D touch via Info.plist.

I've got 2 items ('Item 0' and 'Item 1') and want them ordered in that order ('0' on top, '1' second option item when 3D-touching app icon) yet, it puts '1' first.  How would I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: in your returned array of shortcut item, just reverse the current order?

Comment: My 2 shortcuts are defined in the 'Info.plist' file as key:UIApplicationShortItems.  I don't return an array.  You are saying that the 3D touch items can be done programatically?

Comment: it can be done programmatically. I think the example in apple document is done programmatically. If you define it in plist, you can also just reverse the current order and try again.

Comment: Here's sample how to do it programmatically (shortcut items): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ApplicationShortcuts/Listings/ApplicationShortcuts_AppDelegate_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016545-ApplicationShortcuts_AppDelegate_swift-DontLinkElementID_3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the order is defined via Info.plist file, the priority is driven by the stacking order in the array (Item 0 -> Item 1 ... n). However, when invoked by the user the display order is dynamically allocated for the Item 0 to be within the shortest distance to the initial icon, which in some situations inverses the list order without changing priority stacking.

When the list is displayed below the app icon: the vertical order is 0, 1, 2, 3. When the list is displayed above the app icon: the vertical order is 3, 2, 1, 0. In both scenarios the list priority is the same, item of the highest priority is closest to the initial touch point (app icon) on the screen.

Remains to be checked whether this behavior is persistent for programmatically defined UIApplicationShortcutItem's, or becomes absolute without the inverse of the array subject to placement of the app icon.

Comment: Did you find it somewhere in Apple's documentation?